# gridcontrol syncfusion with a 24hr time format

Tags: c#, grid, syncfusion

Sorry abt this basic question. 
I have a syncfusion grid control which shows time formats in 12pm, am format. The underlying data source has a datetime format. 
What events should I use to change the date display to a 24hr format
Sun

Answer (score 2):

The following settings will enable a grid cell to have date time value in 24 hour format.

```
  this.gridControl1[2, 2].CellValueType = typeof(DateTime);
  this.gridControl1[2, 2].CellValue = new DateTime(2012, 5, 23, 16, 34, 48);
  this.gridControl1[2, 2].Format = "dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss"; //Output is: 23/05/12 16:34:48
```